# Meaning of radical ⼃ - WaniKani meaning not the same as what I found online

Tags: kanji, radicals

I recently started learning Japanese and yesterday I started with my Kanji journey. I found https://www.wanikani.com/ and started using this tool to learn Kanji.

In the first review I learned this review I learned this radical: ⼃ and according to WaniKani it's meaning is *slide*. Which for some reason sounded odd to me, so I went online to find the meaning of this radical and on [https://kanjialive.com/](https://kanjialive.com/214-traditional-kanji-radicals/) I found this meaning: *diagonal sweeping stroke*.

Now this confuses me, because I thought that all radicals had their own meaning that could be used as a 'word', but then why would the meaning be so different. And I also did find nothing about *slide* online.

But maybe it's just like a synonym.

Comment: The items WaniKani refers to as radicals are just components for mnemonics they've written specifically for the website. They're not teaching "meanings" of radicals, just "names" for them, which they assigned (note that they don't say it means slide, just that its name is slide). The intention of the site isn't to teach etymologically accurate breakdowns of kanji into components, but to make mnemonics that are easy for English speakers to remember.

Comment: Is it me or is it strange that I need to memorise these mnemonics instead of actual radicals and use mnemonics to remember the actual meaning?

Comment: WaniKani has a FAQ and its own forums if you want to know why they constructed the site the way they did. To me it's not that strange, since many radicals have bland meanings or meanings that are very similar to other radicals, and giving them original names that are evocative of their shapes works well for mnemonics.

Comment: Ok I will check that out.

Yes I understand why they use mnemonics, but I don't understand why they don't link to their real meaning. Knowing the name as slide, won't help me with knowing what it actually means here.

Because for other, they use the real meaning. ⼇ = lid; ⼈ = person; ⼒ = power, ...

Or am I completely missing the point here?

Comment: The shape ⼃is just a shape used in kanji. If you were under the impression that ⼃could be used as a word in Japanese, that's mistaken. Even "diagonal sweeping stroke" is just literally a description of what it looks like.

Comment: Ok, I can see that. But for example ⼀ means one, correct? The name for this radical in WaniKani is ground... I just can't seem to understand why I need to remember this as ground when it's just one line -> one.

Comment: You'd be better served having this discussion on WaniKani. They have a synonym feature if you decide you don't want to use the name they assigned.

Comment: Why do you need to memorize the names of those components in the first place?

Comment: I was just confused by the meaning and importance of those components. I thought I had to memorize them to learn Kanji. But that's not the case?